# How to combine AND and OR with Knex?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knex.js

I am unable to create the following SQL query in Knex:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE (code = 'export') AND (status = 'failed' OR status = 'complete')
```

Using the code:

```
const queryResult = await this.db('tasks')
        .select('*')
        .where(async function () {

          if ('code' in query) {
            this.where('code', query.code)
          }

          if ('status' in query) {
            if (isArray(query.status)) {
              return query.status.map(status => this.orWhere('status', status))
            } else {
              this.andWhere('status', query.status)
            }
          }
        })
        .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
```

When supplying an array of multiple statuses it disregards the "code = export" value and selects everything.

Comment: You don't need `orWhere` and a loop. Just use `whereIn('status', query.status)`

Comment: That's because you are building a query like `code = 'exports' OR status = 'failed' OR status = 'complete'` - think about it, in this code path there is no `andWhere`, only `orWhere`! You need to put the `OR`s into a `.andWhere(function () {})` call to create the `AND` and the parentheses, or better yet, use `code = 'export' AND status IN ('failed', 'complete')` using `andWhere(status, 'IN', query.status)` in the array case.

Comment: `.where()` callback is not async

Answer (score 0):

Use [modify](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify).

```
const queryResult = await this.db('tasks')
    .select('*')
    .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if ('code' in query) {
        queryBuilder.where('code', query.code)
      }
      if ('status' in query) {
        if (isArray(query.status)) {
          query.status.map(status => queryBuilder.orWhere('status', status))
        } else {
          queryBuilder.andWhere('status', query.status)
        }
      }
    })
    .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
```

Comment: The issue is still that a query with only ORs is built in the case the OP described. A `.andWhere(function...)` is needed to solve it.

Comment: no need to use modify for this basic case

Answer (score 0):

```
const query = knex('tasks');

if ('code' in query) {
  query.where('code', query.code);
}

if ('status' in query) {
  query.where(builder => {
    const statuses = isArray(query.status) ? query.status : [query.status];
    for (let status of statuses) {
      builder.orWhere('status', status);
    }
  });
}

const result = await query;
```